# Algorithm for drawing a 5 point star

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I'm currently working on a solution for drawing a standard 5-point star on the canvas using JavaScript. I'm part way there but can't figure it out entirely. I'd appreciate any tips or pointers anyone might have.

Comment: Five lines between five points on a circle, spread `4/5 pi` from each other (spanning the circle twice)?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 4):

I made some changes to the code that Chris posted so it would work for me:

```
var alpha = (2 * Math.PI) / 10; 
var radius = 12;
var starXY = [100,100]

canvasCtx.beginPath();

for(var i = 11; i != 0; i--)
{
    var r = radius*(i % 2 + 1)/2;
    var omega = alpha * i;
    canvasCtx.lineTo((r * Math.sin(omega)) + starXY[0], (r * Math.cos(omega)) + starXY[1]);
}
canvasCtx.closePath();
canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#000";
canvasCtx.fill();
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

n point star, points are distributed evenly around a circle. Assume the first point is at 0,r (top), with the circle centred on 0,0, and that we can construct it from a series of triangles rotated by 2π/(2n+1):

[image: 5 point star]

Define a rotation function:

```
function rotate2D(vecArr, byRads) {
    var mat = [ [Math.cos(byRads), -Math.sin(byRads)], 
                [Math.sin(byRads), Math.cos(byRads)] ];
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i < vecArr.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = [ mat[0][0]*vecArr[i][0] + mat[0][1]*vecArr[i][1],
                      mat[1][0]*vecArr[i][0] + mat[1][1]*vecArr[i][1] ];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Construct a star by rotating n triangles:

```
function generateStarTriangles(numPoints, r) {
    var triangleBase = r * Math.tan(Math.PI/numPoints);
    var triangle = [ [0,r], [triangleBase/2,0], [-triangleBase/2,0], [0,r] ];
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
       result[i] = rotate2D(triangle, i*(2*Math.PI/numPoints));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Define a function to draw any given array of polygons:

```
function drawObj(ctx, obj, offset, flipVert) {
   var sign=flipVert ? -1 : 1;
   for(var objIdx=0; objIdx < obj.length; ++objIdx) {
      var elem = obj[objIdx];
      ctx.moveTo(elem[0][0] + offset[0], sign*elem[0][1] + offset[1]);
      ctx.beginPath();
      for(var vert=1; vert < elem.length; ++vert) {
        ctx.lineTo(elem[vert][0] + offset[0], sign*elem[vert][1] + offset[1]);
      }
      ctx.fill();
   }
}
```

Use the above to draw a 5 point star:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var offset = [canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2];
ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
var penta = generateStarTriangles(5, 200);
drawObj(ctx, penta, offset, true);
```

See it here http://jsbin.com/oyonos/2/

Comment: Great answer. Please, in `drawObj`, change `penta[objIdx]` with `obj[objIdx]`

Comment: Is there any source to look out for these trigonometric functions, like which trigonometric functions can draw what.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem where Turtle Geometry makes things simple:

5-point star:

repeat 5 times:

fwd 100,
   right 144,
   fwd 100,
   left 72,

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the inner bits and a complete circle is 2 * PI radians. In the example below r is the radius of the encompassing circle. Code below is from an open source project (http://github.com/CIPowell/PhyloCanvas)

```
var alpha = (2 * Math.PI) / 10; 
// works out the angle between each vertex (5 external + 5 internal = 10)
var r_point = r * 1.75; // r_point is the radius to the external point

for(var i = 11; i != 0; i--) // or i could = 10 and you could use closePath at the end
{
var ra = i % 2 == 1 ? rb: r;

var omega = alpha * i; //omega is the angle of the current point
    //cx and cy are the center point of the star.
node.canvas.lineTo(cx + (ra * Math.sin(omega)), cy + (ra * Math.cos(omega)));

}

//Store or fill.
```

NB: This is one of those many ways to skin a cat things, I'm sure someone else has another way of doing it. Also, the reason for the decremental loop rather than the incremental is preformance. i != 0 is more efficient than i < 10 and i-- is more efficient than i++. But performance matters a lot for my code, it might not be so crucial for yours.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for such an algorithm myself and wondered if I could invent one myself. Turned out not to be too hard. So here is a small function to create stars and polygons, with options to set the number of point, outer radius, and inner radius (the latter does only apply to stars).

```
function makeStar(c, s, x, y , p, o, i) {
    var ct = c.getContext('2d');
    var points =  p || 5;
    var outer_radius = o || 100;
    var inner_radius = i || 40;
    var start_x = x || 100;
    var start_y = y || 100;
    var new_outer_RAD, half_new_outer_RAD;
    var RAD_distance = ( 2 * Math.PI / points);  
    var RAD_half_PI = Math.PI /2; 
    var i;
    ct.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
    ct.beginPath();

    for (i=0; i <= points; i++) {
        new_outer_RAD = (i + 1) * RAD_distance;     
        half_new_outer_RAD = new_outer_RAD - (RAD_distance / 2); 

        if (s) {
            ct.lineTo(start_x + Math.round(Math.cos(half_new_outer_RAD - RAD_half_PI) * inner_radius), start_y + Math.round(Math.sin(half_new_outer_RAD - RAD_half_PI) * inner_radius));
        }

        ct.lineTo(start_x + Math.round(Math.cos(new_outer_RAD - RAD_half_PI) * outer_radius), start_y + Math.round(Math.sin(new_outer_RAD - RAD_half_PI) * outer_radius));   

    }

    ct.stroke();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

makeStar(canvas);
makeStar(canvas, true, 120,200, 7, 110, 40);
```

Comment: sorry, I had some problems pasting the script, the last two lines fell out of the script box. Anyway, these are the parameters:

makeStar(canvas, star (bool), x offset, y offset, # points, outer radius, inner radius)